# USB-Ports do not work completely on a DELL Latitude D620 with Windows 10 (SSD)

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, dell-latitude, hardware-detection

I have equipped my old DELL Latitue D620 notebook with an SSD and installed Win 10 Pro on it. The overall performance is surprisingly good.

Now I also have a port replicator, which has a total of 4 x USB 2.0 ports and the notebook itself has 2 x USB 2.0 ports.

Strangely, however, none of these USB ports work correctly. For example, I plugged an old Bluetooth USB stick into the notebook and the port replicator and found an old Toshiba driver for Win 10 on the net, which, according to the thread replyer, works without problems on his Latitude D620, but for me the Bluetooth USB stick only works with restrictions, i.e. it finds my Jabra 85t Earpods, for example, but nothing more.

Furthermore, I wanted to plug in an external SD/MMC card reader on the port replicator and also on the notebook, but it is not recognized properly. Although the drives are displayed in the Device Manager, but not in Windows Explorer.

[Win 10 Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOU2X.png)

[Win 10 Device Manager | All Devices and USB-Smartcard Reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLe6n.png)

The same thing happens when I plug in a FujiFilm XP140 digital camera. This is also not recognized and thus access to the internal camera memory is neither possible via Windows Explorer nor via another app.

However, normal USB memory sticks are recognized and can be used.

**Who can tell me what I can do to fully use devices connected via the USB ports on the Latitude D620 notebook or port replicator?**

Best thanks in advance for your support!

Best regards
SophistiCat